# MS SQL merge column A with column B replacing the value of A with B unless it's NULL

Tags: sql-server

I tried googling this I'm not exactly sure how to formulate my search. I searched for merge, combining, replacing. Any other suggestions or advice are welcome. The results I find don't replace the field of column A but either adds both values/strings like `colA field 'John'+" "+'Smith'`. This is not what I'm looking for. i found someone else with the same question but without the right answer [here](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?68287-How-can-I-combine-two-columns-into-one-column-using-SQL)

The [concat function](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-concat-function.php) is not what I'm looking for since it only adds the values and not replace them. (Not sure in which versions of SQL it works)

**Have this:**

```
table1
        id  row text
row1    1   1   AAA     
row2    1   2   BBB     
row3    1   3   CCC     
row4    1   4   DDD     
row5    2   1   aaa
row6    2   2   bbb

table2
        id  row text    
row1    1   1   AAA     
row2    1   3   CCCCC       
row3    2   1   aaa     
row4    2   2   bbbbb
```

**Desired result:**

```
Display
        id  row text
row1    1   1   AAA
row2    1   2   BBB
row3    1   3   CCCCC
row4    1   4   DDD
row5    2   1   aaa
row6    2   2   bbbbb
```

I don't want to modify the original records and table designs.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT table1.id
     , table1.row
     , Coalesce(table2.text, table1.text) As text
FROM   table1
 LEFT
  JOIN table2
    ON table2.id  = table1.id
   AND table2.row = table1.row
```

The [`Coalesce()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) function takes a minimum of two parameters and returns the first non-null value from those values.

Also note that we're performing an outer join so that we have all values from `table1` and where we can, we match with values from `table2`. If you were to change it to `SELECT * ...` then it may be more illustrative.